# Add Column from a Query request to a Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, request

I have table A with 3 columns (X1,X2,X3) and more than 100000 rows. I want to add a new column "X4" in the table A. The column X4 = X2 - X3.

Thanks!

I tried

SELECT X2 - X3 AS X4
FROM table A

But i dont know how to add X4 into table A.

Comment: usually with an alter table command.  This is denormalization however and should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Use below simple approach

```
ALTER TABLE table_A ADD COLUMN X4 INT64;

UPDATE table_A SET X4 = X2 - X3 WHERE true;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail! It worked! I can´t vote to say your answer is useful.